# How to search similar images on facebook database?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have an image and I want to find similar images on facebook database and then trace the profile which the image represents. Note that the image I have is not on the facebook database and I am looking for **similar** images.

Comment: You can not search for images on Facebook like that. And even if you could, you can not get from a photo to a user profile. The user would have to grant your app permission first, and even then the link to their profile you can get via API, would only work for friends. Long story short: What you want here, is absolutely, massively impossible.

Comment: Alright ! Thanks ! I am new to development